# AWS Lambda function loop all files in a s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

For AWS Lambda, I can easily add a s3 object trigger on new objects create event. In other words, any new update/upload file will trigger to run my lambda function.

#### Questions

- But how about for the existing files?
- Any method to let Lambda to deal with the previously uploaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Only on creation, deletion, or RRS object lost.

> Currently, Amazon S3 can publish the following events:
>
> A new object created event—Amazon S3 supports multiple APIs to create objects. You can request notification when only a specific API is used (e.g., s3:ObjectCreated:Put) or you can use a wildcard (e.g., s3:ObjectCreated:*) to request notification when an object is created regardless of the API used.
>
> An object removal event—Amazon S3 supports deletes of versioned and unversioned objects. For information about object versioning, see Object Versioning and Using Versioning.
>
> You can request notification when an object is deleted or a versioned object is permanently deleted by using the s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete event type. Or you can request notification when a delete marker is created for a versioned object by using s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated. You can also use a wildcard s3:ObjectRemoved:* to request notification anytime an object is deleted. For information about deleting versioned objects, see Deleting Object Versions.
>
> A Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) object lost event—Amazon S3 sends a notification message when it detects that an object of the RRS storage class has been lost.

You can see more at this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html